# python print last element value in XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree, findall

Using ElementTree, I have gone through a ton of post here and can't find any that are specific to my xml.  I want to return the last timestamp in the example xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entities TotalResults="125">
    <Entity Type="defect">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>520342</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="priority">
                <Value></Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="user-08">
                <Value>8/20/2018 9:52:01 PM</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <RelatedEntities/>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Type="defect">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>520574</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="priority">
                <Value></Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="user-08">
                <Value>8/20/2018 10:52:01 PM<</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <RelatedEntities/>
    </Entity>
</Entities>
```

Comment: Your XML is not well formed -- there is an extra `<` in the second time stamp

Answer (score 0):

With a correctly formed version of your XML above, this will find specifically the last timestamp as a string. Without more information, I can't make sure this will be scalable at all.

```
t = root[-1].find(".//*[@Name='user-08']/Value").text
print(t)
#=> 8/20/2018 10:52:01 PM
```